# Apache server : Get a virtual file distribute by a script

Tags: python, apache, virtual-file

My problem is the following :
I have build an apache server (with python cgi). I have client that try to get a file like http://mysever/file (which is virtual, it does not exist). Depending of the user agent of the client I would like to serve a different file like  http://mysever/type1/file or http://mysever/type2/file. 
I have tried with ScriptAlias file myscript.py ad I got error 403 Forbidden (my script has been chmoded +x)
I have tried with with Script or Action and I got error 400 Bad Request.
The only thing that works is with Redirect but it seems very ugly.
Can you help me ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution.
In .htaccess file, in the `<Directory>` part, I have used :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^file$ myscript.py
```

Aaaaaaaand it's gone !